# Issues fetching JSON string with ksoap2 in android

Tags: android, json, web-services, ksoap2

I am experiencing what I find to be a VERY strange problem currently. I have database with about 1000 records. I have a web service for fetching these and turning them into a json string. Testing this using soapui or another web service client works perfectly fine.

My problem is that when I fetch the data using ksoap2 in android it crashes, and here is the crazy part: it only crashes sometimes!?!? 
After quite a bit of debugging I have noticed that the JSON i get in android is ALMOST the same as the one I get in eg. SOAPUI.
The problems I have seen are

1. it has removed a ":" between a key and value- eg. "id""2" instead of "id":"2"
2. it might be missing a '"' on either side of a key or a value. eg: "id:"2" instead of "id":"2"
3. An entire key has been removed, eg: "name":"myname","2" instead of "name":"myname","id":"2". Furthermore it is NOT the same place that something is removed every time...

I am seeing these errors (when I use logs) before I start parsing the json (which of course fails if it is not valid json). Ss the web service is returning the correct thing (according to SOAPUI) I'm assuming it is ksoap that somehow messes up parsing the soap response.

Keep in mind as well that it occasionally works and the json has all the data and is successfully parsed!

Here is my code calling the web service (The json is ~345.000 characters):

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, method);
input.addPropsToRequest(request);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new 
SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.implicitTypes = true;
envelope.dotNet = false;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
androidHttpTransport.call(soap_action, envelope);
String json = envelope.getResponse().toString();
```